# Shifting columns down with pandas in Kaggle print() views

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, kaggle

While working with pandas in Kaggle, when I issue the print() command for certain columns of my dataset, some of my columns scroll down during display.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J0I1.png)

I want all the columns to appear next to each other. My screen resolution is (1920*1080) in case there is a problem with the screen resolution.

Comment: just do df[['name_col_1','name_col_2','name_col_3']].head(n=100)